# Observer pattern for clickable 2D Elements?

Tags: directx, design-patterns, menu

So i am currently thinking about the best way to handle and implement clickable 2D menu elements in a very simple DirectX Game.
I very much like the idea of having subscribers to a event where they are getting notified (e.g. the mouse click).

My question now is: Where and how do i determine which subscriber gets notified by a mouse click? Does the publisher know about all the positional data of the subscribers? Should the publisher just notify all 2D menu elements, so that they need to handle this event (check if the clicked position intersects with their own dimension)? Is this even a good idea?

As already stated, this will be a very basic game, so performance should not be any real issue yet. Still i always like to use some of the best practices, so i will at least learn some part of it (thus i will not implement a complete GUI system, only the subscriber part).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some informal thoughts, specifically about clickable menu items...

1. You're 100% correct to not worry much about performance here.
2. Menus are typically stateful, navigating a tree of states. So it may make more sense to alert a "menu node" which which of the several choices they made. At the individual button/item level, they could know their 2d boxes, and sure asking each one "was it you, at xy?" is just fine. Since you'll have probably < 100 menu items to click on at any time.
3. Often at the end of a menu is something more interactive, like "enter your name" or the game starts playing or such.

For clickable areas that aren't menus, if there's not many, it's probably still fine to ask each one for each click, "would you like to handle this click?".

On the other hand, to handle clicks on thousands of quickly-moving sprites, a different approach would be indicated.